# If a pandas df column has a specific value, another column only allow a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, filter, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that has a department, its function, its subfunction and its sub-subfunction. A example of the dataframe would be this:

```py
d = [['Dept1'  ,               'HR'  ,        'Talent'     ,     'Good Employee 3'],
    ['Dept2'  ,               'IT'   ,      'Garbage'  ,  'Analysis HR 2'],
       ['Dept3'   ,              'IT'  ,        'Tech Sup' ,           'IT Tech 2'],
      [ 'Dept4'   ,              'HR'  ,        'Hardware' ,        'Trash Can' ] ,             
      [ 'Dept5'   ,              'MKT'  ,         'Sales'  ,         'Facebook Promo 1'],
       ['Dept6'   ,              'MKT'  ,       'Communication',     'Car profit']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Department', 'Function' ,     'Subfunction' ,  'Sub-subfunction'])
```

```
       Department           Function      Subfunction   Sub-subfunction
0        Dept1                 HR          Talent          Good Employee 3
1        Dept2                 IT         Garbage     Analysis HR 2
2        Dept3                 IT          Tech Sup            IT Tech 2
3        Dept4                 HR          Hardware         Trash Can               
4        Dept5                 MKT           Sales           Facebook Promo 1
5        Dept6                 MKT         Communication     Car profit
```

I need to create a rule that would check if a department has a certain value in function, it only allow a possible list of values in subfunction. Then, in subfunction the same, each unique value would allow only a possible list of values in sub-subfunction.

The mapping would be the following:

```
subfunction = {'HR': ['Talent', 'Analysis Human'],
              'IT': ['Tech Sup', 'Hardware'],
              'MKT': ['Sales', 'Communication']}

sub_subfunction = {'Talent': ['Good Employee 1', 'Good Employee 2', 'Good Employee 3'],
                   'Analysis Human': [ 'Analysis HR 1', 'Analysis HR 2', 'Analysis HR 3'],
                   'Tech Sup': ['IT Tech 1', 'IT Tech 2', 'IT Tech 3', 'Tech Master'],
                   'Hardware': ['PC pieces', 'Phone pieces'],
                   'Sales': ['Car profit', 'Bolt profit'],
                   'Communication': ['Facebook Promo 1', 'Instagram Promo 1']}
```

In this dataframe, this function would return the ones that do not obey this rule, in this example it would return:

```
       Department           Function      Subfunction   Sub-subfunction
1        Dept2                 IT         Garbage    Analysis HR 2
3        Dept4                 HR          Hardware         Trash Can               
4        Dept5                 MKT           Sales           Facebook Promo 1
5        Dept6                 MKT         Communication     Car profit
```

What would be the best way to apply those rules?
As you can see, the values of the dataframe can be outside the values of the mapped dictionary (although I can have the "Function" values all mapped in the subfunction dictionary if that helps too much).

If it also can help, it could be realized in steps. First using a condition to deal with the Function/Subfunction mapping and then dealing separetly with each condition of subfunction / sub-subfunction (although really not ideal)

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 1):

```py
subfunction = {'HR': ['Talent', 'Analysis Human'],
              'IT': ['Tech Sup', 'Hardware'],
              'MKT': ['Sales', 'Communication']}
sub_subfunction = {'Talent': ['Good Employee 1', 'Good Employee 2', 'Good Employee 3'],
                   'Analysis Human': [ 'Analysis HR 1', 'Analysis HR 2', 'Analysis HR 3'],
                   'Tech Sup': ['IT Tech 1', 'IT Tech 2', 'IT Tech 3', 'Tech Master'],
                   'Hardware': ['PC pieces', 'Phone pieces'],
                   'Sales': ['Car profit', 'Bolt profit'],
                   'Communication': ['Facebook Promo 1', 'Instagram Promo 1']}

df[~((df.apply(lambda x: x[2] in subfunction[x[1]], axis=1)) & (df.apply(lambda x: x[3] in sub_subfunction[x[2]], axis=1)))]
```

output

```
Department  Function    Subfunction Sub-subfunction
1   Dept2   IT  Analysis Human  Analysis HR 2
3   Dept4   HR  Hardware    Good Employee 1
4   Dept5   MKT Sales   Facebook Promo 1
5   Dept6   MKT Communication   Car profit
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can add all conditions in the same line, this way you would have to filter one by one, no?

Comment: First `df.apply(lambda x: x[1] in x[2], axis=1)` is evaluated the performed `&` with `df.apply(lambda x: x[2] in x[3], axis=1)`. Instead of doing one by one, you can add all conditions.

Comment: Can you please use the variables I gave in the example and hard code? For each value in column "Function" there is a list of possible value in Subfunction and, for each of those, a list in Sub-subfunction.

How would you evaluate all the 3 Function categories at the same time?

Comment: have you tried the code snippet? `x[1] in x[2]`  and `x[2] in x[3]` does the same what you are asking.

Comment: Oh sorry, let me reformulate the question, maybe it is my fault and it was a bad example. The word itself of the Function does not necessary contain on the other and so on, they may be totally different worlds.

Comment: Corrected now, sorry!

Comment: `Good Employees 1` or `Good Employee 1` ??

Comment: Hello, what happens if in the data frame has values that are not mapped in the dictionary? It is returning an error

Comment: That is upto you, do you want to ignore it or keep it. Depending on that you can modify the code.

Comment: Ok, I just re-corrected the code. Basically what I want is to know how to use those dictionaries with multiple entries to filter a column (even if in the dataframe there are values outside the mapped dictionary). Thanks a lot!